# Ad hoc 'Logmein Rescue' style remote desktopping?

Tags: vnc, rdp

I want to support Windows users by viewing and controlling their desktops remotely in a simple, hassle-free way a la Logmein Rescue. Is this possible?

Scenario:

Hapless Windows user: "Geoff 9100, please, please help me. I have a virus and it's wiping my files and making me sad."

Geoff 9100: "No problem. I'm a Windows virus-killing ninja. Go to this website: www.helpmepleasegodhelpmeescapethiswindowspain.com"

[A plugin, program, script of some kind implants something or other which enables RDP or VNC or somesuch technology enabling easy location and connection.]

HWU: "Geoff 9100, this is amazing! You're controlling my screen as if you're using my mouse and keyboard! Your amazing! I'm finding myself becoming attracted to you as I watch your deft virus-killing skills saving my bacon. What's your number? Maybe we can get some coffee sometime of something. A movie maybe or you know, something."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had good luck with "TeamViewer" (http://www.teamviewer.com/).  It works on Mac, Linux, and Windows, and will let you friend IM, or send you via any other method, a login code to control his computer.